# Two ways of saying span

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Suppose $V$ is a vector space, and $v_1,...,v_n$ spans $V$. Is that equivalent to saying that $V=\operatorname{span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: No, it is incorrect. $V\subseteq\text{span}\{v_1,..,v_n\}$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the two statements are equivalent.

Here is a definition quoted from Friedberg:

> A subset S of a vector space V generates (or spans) V  if span(S) = V. In this case, we also say that the vectors of S generate (or  span) V.

Friedberg, Stephen H.. Linear Algebra (p. 31). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.

---

You run into issues if you try to define what it means to span in another way. For example, we commonly define a basis as follows:

> A basis of a vector space V is a set $(v_1,...,v_n)$ of vectors that is independent and also spans V.

Artin, Michael. Algebra (Page 88). Pearson Education. Kindle Edition.

But now consider that $S = \{(1,0), (0,1) \}$ is an independent set and spans $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If we only require that $V \subseteq \text{Span } S$ in order for $S$ to span $V$, then we get that $S$ is an independent set that spans every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and so is a basis for every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$, which is not correct.

Comment: The definition of basis supplied here is incomplete. A basis is defined as a set of linearly independent vectors **in $V$** that spans $V$. You can check the definitions on [Brilliant](https://brilliant.org/wiki/bases/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)), [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorBasis.html) and most other websites.

Comment: The [first book by Friedberg you quoted](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/420textbook.pdf) agrees with this on page 35 and specifies explicitly that a basis of $V$ has to be a subset of $V$.

Answer (score -1):

Saying that $V$ is spanned by $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ means that every vector in $V$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_i$. Hence $V$ is a subspace of $\text{span}\{v_1,...,v_n\}$.

For example, $V=\{(k,0):k\in\mathbb R\}$ is spanned by $(1,0),(0,1)$ over the field of real numbers. But, $V\subset\text{span}\{v_i\}=\mathbb R^2$.

---

**Note**: In case you add the condition $v_1,...,v_n\in V$, then $\text{span}\{v_i\}\subseteq V$ by closure property of $V$. Then it can be concluded that $V=\text{span}\{v_i\}$.

Comment: By saying *every* vector in $V$ can be spanned by a set of vectors $S$ in $V$ then $span(S) = V$. This is much stronger than saying $V$ is a subspace of $S$.

Comment: Taylor, I gave an example. $A=\{(k,0):k\in\mathbb R\}$ is spanned by the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2(\mathbb R)$ but $A\neq\mathbb R^2$. The question doesn't mention that the vectors belong to $V$.

Comment: Edited to add that condition.